# Google App Engine API - Guava Dependency Conflict

Tags: scala, google-app-engine, sbt, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use the GCS library in my project:

```
val GoogleCloud = Seq(
  "com.google.appengine.tools" % "appengine-gcs-client" % "0.5"  exclude("com.google.guava", "guava-jdk5"),
  "com.google.appengine" % "appengine-api-stubs" % "1.9.28",
  "com.google.appengine" % "appengine-api-1.0-sdk" % "1.9.28",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0-rc2"
)
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
```

I added the `exclude` above as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155799/java-app-engine-call-to-gcsservice-createorreplace-results-in-stopwatch-createun) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same problem, **exclude didn't work** for me.
After a two days of searching and trying everything I found the following:

Somehow Eclipse didn't delete all jars from the target/MyAppWeb-1.1/WEB-INF/lib/ folder before compiling new WAR during deployment to appengine. So there was still file guava-jdk5.jar remained from my previous steps, no matter that I excluded it from dependencies. Some process was holding these jars because I had to restart windows to be able to delete all content of the target folder. 
After that and fresh recompiling and redeployment the error doesn't appear anymore.

So **try to check your generated WAR, maybe there is guava-jdk5.jar, forgotten from any previous compilation.** In that case **delete all content of the target folder then recompile and redeploy**.